# How to clean a string and keep only alpha words in Javascript

Tags: javascript, split

I have user generated strings coming in and I need to "clean" them and keep only words that containt ONLY alpha letters. Eg.

- "3 apples" -> "apples"
- "4 kg. apples" -> "apples"
- "morning 25 lim. edition" -> "morning edition" (lim. is not only alpha)

I thought of doing a split on " " and then iterating over the words and then adding to the result only sub-strings that include only letters. Any idea how to do this in the most efficient way?

Comment: `function filter(input) {
        var s = input.split(' '), str = [];
        s.forEach(function (a) {
            /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(a) && str.push(a)
        }, '');
        return str.join(' ');
    }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Useless question then... I did not downvote but whoever did, they are correct... Have you read the link I have shared ? Have many point have you followed while posting this question ? No efforts whatsoever.....

Comment: referring to a long article is useless. You should try and point to your issue and not give a 500 page article to read. I am no newbie to stackoverflow. People love downgrading by simply not seeing code in a question. I could have put some stupid code just to avoid that...and probably not so useless...as 3 people took their time to answer.

Comment: That page is just a single page. not 500 pages.. It is not always about code, people wants to see the efforts which are not specified in your question.. You said you are not a _newbie_ but your question does say so... Be careful with the words you are using..

Comment: And how exactly would you see how much effort I put into it?! Mind reader?

Comment: Efforts/Research should reflect in your question.. That is the only source you have..

Comment: As I said, this is useless. People should not assume stuff. Especially when passing judgement on others.

Comment: That is philosophy.. Not sure how to apply that in programming... In __SO__, people judge it based on the efforts then could evaluate expressed in Question.. And that is probably only way they got :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let getAlphaWords = (words) => {
    // A case-insensitive regex to match alpha characters
    const ALPHA_REGEX = /^[a-z]+$/i;

    // A function to test if a word only contains alpha characters
    let isAlphaWord = (word) => ALPHA_REGEX.test(word);

    // Split into words and filter out all that contain non-alpha
    let alphas = words.split(' ').filter(isAlphaWord);

    // rejoin the words
    return alphas.join(' ');
}
```

This can be used like so:

```
getAlphaWords("3 apples"); // "apples"
getAlphaWords("4 kg. apples"); // "apples"
getAlphaWords("morning 25 lim. edition"); // "morning edition"
```

---

Here is the above in non-ES6 code:

```
var getAlphaWords = function (words) {
    // A case-insensitive regex to match alpha characters
    var ALPHA_REGEX = /^[a-z]+$/i;

    // A function to test if a word only contains alpha characters
    var isAlphaWord = function (word) {
        return ALPHA_REGEX.test(word);
    }

    // Split into words and filter out all that contain non-alpha
    var alphas = words.split(' ').filter(isAlphaWord);

    // rejoin the words
    return alphas.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter, why did you downvote this answer? It answers the question with well-structured and well-explained code. If you disagree with the question then downvote/flag the question, but do not downvote answers - judge them on their own merit.

Comment: I did not downvote. Someone else did. What language is your answer for? Not Javascript. Seems like coffescript?

Comment: Hi @checklist, this is [ES6 JavaScript](http://es6-features.org/). I will edit the answer to add non-ES6 code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isWord(inptWord,wordsArray){
  try{
    var wordRegex = new RegExp(/[a-z]+$/,"i");
    if(wordRegex.test(inptWord)){
      wordsArray.push(inptWord);
    }
  }catch(err){
    console.error("Err in fn. isWord : %s",err);
  }
  return wordsArray;
}

function getWordsOnly(inptString){
  var resultString = "";
  try{
    if(typeof inptString == "string"){
      var splitWords = inptString.split(" ");
      var wordsArray = new Array();
      for(var i in splitWords){
        wordsArray = isWord(splitWords[i],wordsArray);
      }
      resultString = wordsArray.join(" ");
    }
  }catch(err){
    console.error("Err in fn. getWordsOnly : %s",err);
  }
  return resultString;
}
```

// getWordsOnly("morning 25 lim. edition"); == morning edition